# Disable transfer-encoding: chunked in Spring Webflux responses

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-web

I created bunch of REST API end points using Spring Webflux reactive libraries. The issue I am facing now is that the responses that spring Webflux returns have **transfer-encoding: chunked** HTTP header. Because of which client side application using library like Axios (https://github.com/axios/axios) promise based HTTP client from the browser javascript is failing. How can we turnoff **transfer-encoding: chunked** ?

Example Response from Spring webflux app using curl:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
<
[{"default_project_id":"admin","description" .......
"name":**"use* Connection #0 to host 10.1.0.9 left intact**
r1"}},"links":{"self":"http://10.10.10.51:5000/v3/users/f6ee9d6217404d2ba73f323edff06bf8"},
"password_expires_at":null,
"id":"f6ee9d6217404d2ba73f323edff06bf8"}]
```

Please help. I am seeing the entire response but the chunking of the response is throwing off http client libraries especially consuming them from web browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can disable chunked encoding with Reactor Netty (the default server used by Spring Boot + WebFlux). The alternative would be to set the `Content-Length` header, which means buffering the whole response before writing it to the network. That's not really optimal for backpressure support.

I looked up the axios client and I've only found an [opened issue about HTTP streaming support](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/479), which is different from `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. Could you elaborate more about how you came to that conclusion?